# PDFBox text group

Tags: pdfbox

In PDFBox I would like to group the `Test1` and `Test2` texts together. So if the texts are selected and copied in the generated pdf, they will be selected in the right order `Test1 Test2 Test3` (not `Test1 Test3 Test2`).

```
content.setLeading(15);

content.beginText();
content.newLineAtOffset(100, 100);
content.showText("Test1");
content.newLine();
content.showText("Test2");
content.endText();

content.beginText();
content.newLineAtOffset(300, 100);
content.showText("Test3");
content.endText();
```

Comment: The order in which some tool selects and copies text is up to the tool. You can try and give hints, e.g. by creating structure information, but a PDF viewer is not required to follow your hints.

Comment: Can you give me an example how can I do it on the code above?

Comment: Unfortunately no; maybe @TilmanHausherr has an idea...

Comment: No, structure information is one of my weak points.